# best way to match one column in dataframe to multiple columns in another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have this df1:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Sara',  'John', 'Christine'],

                   'email': ['sara@example.com', 'john@example.com', 'Christine@example.com']})
```

df1:

```
    name       email
0   Sara       sara@example.com
1   John       john@example.com
2   Christine  Christine@example.com
```

df2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'email_id':['sara@example.com',  np.nan , 'flower@example8.com'],

                   'alternate email': ['sara@example.com', 'john.walker@example.com' , 'Christine33@example.com'],
                   'alternate email2': ['sara13@example.com', 'john@example.com', 'Christine@example.com'],
                   'country': ['US', 'BR', 'CA']})
```

df2:

```
        email_id            alternate email          alternate email2          country
0   sara@example.com       sara@example.com          sara13@example.com             US
1   NaN                    john.walker@example.com  john@example.com                BR
2   flower@example8.com    Christine33@example.com   Christine@example.com          CA
```

Now I would like to match email column in df1 to the `[email_id, alternate email, alternate email2]` columns in df2 and if match is found I got name & country:

**OUTPUT:**

```
    name         email                   Match
0   Sara         sara@example.com         US
1   John         john@example.com         BR
2   Christine    Christine@example.com    CA
```

I used the following code which is working perfectly:

```
df1['Match'] = np.where((df1['email'].isin(df2['email_id'])) | (df1['email'].isin(df2['alternate email2'])) | (df1['email'].isin(df2['alternate email'])), df1.country , 0)
```

but on different data set I got another error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (16622,) (433541,) ()
```

So what is the best standard way to match one column in df1 to multiple columns in df2 and merge the result per matched rows?

Comment: What about the unmatched rows? Do you want to drop those rows?

Comment: @PrantaPalit unmatched rows should be kept or filled with NaN / 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

The idea is to merge df1's 'email' on each column of cols(present in df2 named like email)

```
cols=['email_id', 'alternate email', 'alternate email2']
out=(pd.concat([df1.merge(df2,left_on='email',right_on=x) for x in cols])
       .drop_duplicates(subset=['name'],ignore_index=True).drop(cols,1))
```

output of `out`:

```
    name        email                   country
0   Sara        sara@example.com        US
1   John        john@example.com        BR
2   Christine   Christine@example.com   CA
```

Comment: what if the length of both columns is not same? it will through a `ValueError`

Comment: @PrantaPalit it will work in that case as well